# Serving large-size static files with Jetty

Tags: jetty

I have a Jetty server, which I want to use to server a large-size static files.

I have edited "jetty.xml" adding the following:

```xml
<Set name="handler">
    <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
      <Set name="handlers">
        <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
          <Item>
            <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection">
              <Set name="handlers">
                <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
                  <Item>
                    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
                      <Set name="contextPath">/files</Set>
                      <Set name="handler">
                        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
                          <Set name="directoriesListed">false</Set>
                          <Set name="resourceBase">/path/to/my/files</Set>
                        </New>
                      </Set>
                    </New>
                  </Item>
                </Array>
              </Set>
            </New>
          </Item>
          <Item>
            <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
          </Item>
        </Array>
      </Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
```

It works pretty fine with small files, but with large files the download is too slow and in many times doesn't complete. I'm using Jetty version 9.2.13, and a web browser as the client.

According to "Do not use ResourceHandler to serve static files, use DefaultServlet":
https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/316

I want to use DefaultServlet in my xml instead of ResourceHandler, but I don't know how?

Any help?

Comment: Your configuration works for files up to whatever the FileSystem limits are.  There's no slow down on browsers, command line http clients, or mobile clients.   Can you detail what versions of Jetty you are using?  And what client you are using to test the download with?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt thanks for your concern. The question is edited.

Comment: [Jetty 9.2.13 is rather old (and EOL/End of Life)](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html), is there any reason you cannot use a [stable/supported release](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html)?

Comment: The reason is that I'm using the version that comes with Geoserver (a GIS web server).

Comment: [Newest versions of Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jetty-announce/msg00130.html) running on Linux, and tested from a different Linux machine using Chrome, show no slow down (when downloading a 10GB binary data file), and the network (1/gbps) is nearly saturated.  Perhaps you have something else slowing you down.  Virus scanning perhaps?

Comment: No virus scanning exists. Please help me with using DefaultServlet in my xml instead of ResourceHandler

Comment: Are you using `jetty-distribution`?  if so, create a `${jetty.base}/webapps/files/` directory and put content in it.  Boom you are using a `ServletContextHandler` and a `DefaultServlet` to serve those files.  No XML to create/edit.

Comment: Are you using `jetty-home` (or the older `jetty-distribution`)?   If so, you would never edit the `jetty.xml` to accomplish this goal.  What are you using to start this jetty instance?  (This is a confusing/incomplete question)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, I tried your solution of creating a ${jetty.base}/webapps/files/ directory, and it works fine. Thanks a lot. please make it as an answer, so that I accept it.